# After adding more than 2 support libraries, Errors Errors Errors

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have imported 2 support library files into my project successfully....everything is fine no errors in my project.

But as Ii added another library, the scenario changed. I did not do anything else but just added another support library.

As soon as I click ok I got errors on the supportv4 library. It says it cannot be resolved to a type.

Before adding library no errors were present.

Adding Library:

[image: before]

After Adding Library:

[image: after]

Comment: Why are you adding two support libraries ? Also, which ones ?

Comment: If you add 2 libraries that define the same classes, the system won't know which version to use and will die horribly.  Kind of like what you see.

Comment: Actually they are not support library . one library is for a customized tab strip nd other is Google play services. the new library which i want to add is for customized image view..